# sp2010 - How to implement Multiple Filter parameters for a list view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

I've got a list view that I want to filter as follows:

> (Column1(yes/no) = Yes) OR ((Column2(choice)=New) AND (Column3(choice)=A OR B
>   OR C))

Obviously I'm unable use the OOTB Filter options at this point. I've been trying to use the Query Filter referenced [here](https://madanbhintade.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/sharepoint2010dataviewwebpart/), but I've been unable to figure out how set the operators.

Any advice is appreciated. I do not have access at the server level, but have SPD2010 as a resource and can implement html/js code on the list level.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work - reorder your filters

```
Column3 = A
or
Column3 = B
or
Column3 = C
AND
Column2 = New
OR
Column1 = Yes
```

It would figure out if Column3 is set correctly and then test for the New, so those 4 entries would test correctly for the second half of your filter.
Then your Column1 would override all that

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked like a charm. Appreciate your time!

Comment: Welcome. You just have to remember in filters, since you don't have (), the first 2 are evaluated, then the third is tested against that result, then the fourth is tested against that new result, and so on...... it's going to depend on your AND/OR pattern. Sometimes you have to use calculated fields to simplify your test.